# resque-web as standalone to monitor workers with rails api only application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, resque

Here is the scenario I a trying. 
My rails application is a pure json API. 
I have resque for background jobs. Resque workers run on a separate machine which does not serve web.
I manage this using a common redis server.
I want to use resque-web gem to monitor my resque jobs. I dont want it to run on my web server, but only on jobs server.

The problem is that I cant run resque web as a part of rails api only app.

Is there a way to run resque-web standalone to monitor rails resque worker?

Are there any better alternatives to monitor jobs?

Comment: you can run resque-web as a standalone sinatra based app https://github.com/sshingler/resque-web/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I have been trying to run that. however, I am not able to go past the following error 
`open_http': 500 Internal Server Error (OpenURI::HTTPError)`
any idea how to get this working?

Comment: I guess the error points to a given line of code, you have an HTTPError, maybe an invalid URL, I cannot know without context, code, etc

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want it to run on my web server, but only on jobs server.

First off, you need a webserver to run `resque-web`.

Based on your description I assume you have a web server for Rails (API-only) and a worker server. You have two options: either run `resque-web` as a standalone webserver or as part of Rails.

These options are described in Resque's README's `Standalone` and `Rails 3` chapters: https://github.com/resque/resque#the-front-end

Note that the latter requires a normal Rails app and not an api-only one, so you might have to adjust your setup.